# How to check if passed in parameter is contained in list in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following named query,

select b from BBC b where :sd MEMBER OF b.SDA

```
SDA sd=new SDA();
```

and I am calling `em.createNamedQuery("MyQuery").setParameter("sd",sd);`

But it is returning no results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set any fields in `sd`? I think `sd` parameter is compared to `SDA` collection by calling `equals()` on each element. So, first thing is that you should have `SDA#equals()` implemented, and it should return `true` for the param you pass in the query (i suppose this is not the full code, and you do set some values to `sd`).